# Trouble with jquery .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="expand">
<div class="title" id="SectionTitle2">Academics</div>
<input type="button" onclick="showTitleForm('2');" name="editTitle2" value="Edit Title">
<form id="titleForm2" method="POST" onsubmit="processTitle('titleForm2')" >
    <div id="SectionTitle2-group" class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="SectionTitle" />
    </div>
    <div id="SectionID2-group" class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="SectionID" value="2" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
function processTitle(formID) {

    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

    var formData = {
        'SectionTitle'  : $('input[name=SectionTitle]').val(),
        'SectionID'         : $('input[name=SectionID]').val()
    };

    var id = formData['SectionID'];
    var eg = formID;


    // process the form 
    $.ajax({
        type                        : 'POST',
        url                         : 'editTitle.php',
        data                        : formData,
        dataType                : 'json',
        encode                  : true
    }).done(function(data) { // using the done promise callback
        // log data to the console
        console.log(data);

        // handle errors and validation messages
        if (data.success === false) {
            $('SectionTitle'+id+'-group').addClass('has-error'); // use CSS to make red input
            $(eg).append('<div class="help-block">' 
                                                + data.errors.SectionTitle 
                                                + '</div>'
                                                );
            $('SectionID'+id+'-group').addClass('has-error');
            $(eg).append('<div class="error-block">'
                                                + data.errors.SectionID
                                                + '</div>'
                                                );
        } else { 
            $(eg).append('<div class="alert alert-success">Success!</div>');
            document.getElementById('SectionTitle'+id).innerHTML = formData['SectionTitle'];
            hideAllForms();
        }       
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

}
```

When I click "save", the title changes, the PHP runs exactly right, there are no errors in the console, but no extra div at the end of my form. Any clues?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you stepped through the program with your browser tools? What does `data.success` evaluate to?

Comment: It appears you may need to add the # id selector to your jQuery selector for the form id.

Comment: @isherwood, yes. data.success is evaluating to the boolean true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `eg` variable is set to `titleForm2` when you call the `processTitle()` function which will result in

`$('titleForm2').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Success!</div>');`

later on in your code. You have to change it to

```
  var eg = '#' + formID;
```

in order to get

```
$('#titleForm2').append(...);
```

which will eventually append the new div to the form with an `id` of `#titleForm2`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the pound symbol to your selector.

```
 var eg = '#' + formID;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var eg = formID;
```

Here you are passing `formID` as argument to the function `processTitle`.

In `$(eg)` you forgot to append `#` at the front.

it should be `$("#"+eg)`

else it must be :

```
var eg = "#"+formID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you just pass in the form element itself as `this`.

```
<form id="titleForm2" method="POST" onsubmit="processTitle(this)" >
```

Then in JS

```
function processTitle(form){
   var $form = $(form);// more understandable variable name than `eg`
     ....
     $form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
     ....

    /* processing code then */
    $form.append(".....");

}
```

Comment: Passing "this" didn't work. However, I took your advice to change my variable name. I used "eg" because it's looks like "e.g." which means "for example". Thank you!